# Append nested list in python based on last value and first value of the lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, nested-lists

I have a below python nested list

```
[[text1, data1, text2][text2, data2, text3][text5, data4, text6][text3, data3, text4]]
```

I would like to convert this to

```
[[text1, data1, text2, data2, text3, data3, text4][text5,data4,text6]]
```

Basically, if the last value of the first list is the same as first value of any other list, then it should be combined.

Is there a simple way to do it, or I have to loop through the list with a condition and append it?

Comment: you'll have to write the logic for it

Comment: Shouldn't output be `[[text1, data1, text2, data2, text3, data3, text4],[text5,data4,text6]]` ?  (data4 in place of data5)

Comment: Yes..my bad.. Corrected it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
l = [["text1", "data1", "text2"],["text2", "data2", "text3"],["text5", "data4", "text6"],["text3", "data3", "text4"]]
d = dict()
for each in l:
    d[each[0]] = each[1:]
final = []
keys = list(d.keys())
while len(keys)>0:
    start = keys[0]
    l_list = []
    while start in d:
        l_list+= [start] + d[start]
        keys.remove(start)
        start = l_list.pop()
    l_list+=[start]
    final.append(l_list)
print(final)
```

OUTPUT:
`[['text1', 'data1', 'text2', 'data2', 'text3', 'data3', 'text4'], ['text5', 'data4', 'text6']]`

Comment: I like the way you did it.. Even though it is not something I was looking for, this is much better what I had in mind..